# how does personalisation work in ibm portal version 8?

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm

How can we get session data while writing personalisation business rule in WCM portal 8?

Where I will set data into session so that get this session data while writing personalisation business rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Dynamic Property (Manage Properties tab in the Personalization Editor)  with the name of the session attribute that you want access.  This attribute have to exist into the session.